# underscore in Map function in scala

Tags: scala

A quick question about use of underscore in map function, suppose I have a RDD below:

```
val R_1 = sc.parallelize(List((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)))
R_1.map(x => x._1 + x._2)
```

result is (3, 7, 11)

I got a error when I use
`R_1.map(_._1 + _._2)` to do this.

I dont really understand underscore magic in scala lambda expression. So my question is what is difference between `R_1.map(x => x._1 + x._2)` and `R_1.map(_._1 + _._2)`. Is there any other way to write `R_1.map(x => x._1 + x._2)`?
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each successive underscore implies another argument to the anonymous function. So, `{ _._1 + _._2 }` corresponds to `(a,b) => a._1 + b._2`.

Yes, there is another way, using pattern matching:

```
R_1.map { case (x,y) => x + y }
```